# Access Innermost query in JavaScript / ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I want to print innermost content from following query, 
How can I access plans > personal > title, and print the content on screen.

Thanks a lot!

I get data from **data.js** which is shown below:

```
export default [
  {
    sys: {
      id: "1"
    },
    fields: {
      name: "cloud hosting",
      slug: "cloud-hosting",
      type: "hosting",
      price: 100,
      size: 200,
      capacity: 1,
      featured: true,
      description:
        "The power of SSD + Simplicity of cPanel",
      extras: [
        "Plush pillows and breathable bed linens",
        "Soft, oversized bath towels",
        "Full-sized, pH-balanced toiletries",
        "Complimentary refreshments",
        "Adequate safety/security",
        "Internet",
        "Comfortable beds"
      ],
      plans:[
        {
          fields:{
            personal:{
              title: "personal"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: `{{ plans.map(p => p.fields.personal.title) }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `flatMap`. I'm assuming your data is an array.

```js
var data = [{ sys: { id: "1" }, fields: { name: "cloud hosting", slug: "cloud-hosting", type: "hosting", price: 100, size: 200, capacity: 1, featured: true, description: "The power of SSD + Simplicity of cPanel", extras: [ "Plush pillows and breathable bed linens", "Soft, oversized bath towels", "Full-sized, pH-balanced toiletries", "Complimentary refreshments", "Adequate safety/security", "Internet", "Comfortable beds" ], plans: [{ fields: { personal: { title: "personal" } } }] }}];

result = data.flatMap(({fields})=>fields.plans.map(k=>(k.fields.personal.title)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!